# Random noise when playing Audio with OpenAL on Mac

Tags: macos, audio, core-audio, openal

I am porting a game from iPad to Mac.

Every time I start the game, certain set of sounds when they are being played, have an irritating noise at the end of playback, much like a short duration of heavy static noise.

Also the sounds which produce the noise is not the same on every execution. Each time a different set of sounds have the noise at the end.

Is there any OpenAL settings regarding to this situation to fix it.

Solutions tried:-

Tried to convert the mp3 files into some higher and lower bitrate format and tried to playback. Still noise persists.

Comment: Is it possible that you're passing in a buffer that is larger than your data, and the noise at the end is the result of attempting to interpret those bytes as sound?

Comment: @Gabe Thank you very much man! You are a genius. All I did was add a line of code for memset-ing the allocated memory to zero after malloc. And the noise disappeared :). thanks man.. Post it below and I will mark as Answer. Thank you again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like (get it?) you're passing in a buffer that is larger than your data, and the noise at the end is the result of attempting to interpret those bytes as sound.

Comment: Thank you. Had to make a quick fix, your hint about noise helped and I just memset-ed the buffer to zeros completely before putting in the audio data and then passing it to OpenAL.